# Android AppWidget TextView: How to set background color at run time

Tags: android

I am trying to create an AppWidget, in which the background color of a TextView changes at random at specified periodic interval.

The TextView is defined in layout xml file as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView  
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:background="#ff99ff"
        android:text="Hello Widget" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In update method, i have loaded the layout as

```
RemoteViews remoteView=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_message);
```

To change the background of TextView i used the following statement

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.message, "setBackgroundResource", R.color.col_1);
```

But i am getting a widget saying problem loading widget. If i remove the above line everything works fine.

LogCat says:

> updateAppWidget couldn't find any
>   view, using error view
>
> android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException:
>   view: android.widget.TextView can't
>   use method with RemoteViews:
>   setBackgroundResource(int)

Answer (score 70):

Try this it will work fine.

```
remoteView.setInt(R.id.message, "setBackgroundColor", 
        android.graphics.Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: What if I want to retain the drawable?

Comment: does not work on ViewGroups like LinearLayout, does work on views like TextView

Answer (score 9):

If you have some shape as the background of the textview, where the background is defined in some drawable resource, then you can use

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.change,"setBackgroundResource", R.drawable.my_drawable_new);
```

In above code statement, R.id.change is the TextView with some background resource and you have defined some resources (my_drawable and my drawable_new) in your drawable folder.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/change"
    android:background="@drawable/my_drawable">
</TextView
```

Answer (score 7):

If you want to set the color of the text itself, use

```
remoteViews.setInt(R.id.tvAmountThisYear, "setTextColor",
                android.graphics.Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 7):

contentView.setInt(R.id.tv_contactText, "setBackgroundColor",
                        Color.parseColor(hexColor));

Answer (score 1):

Tomas is correct.  My solution is to make two views with the respective backgrounds and make one INVISIBLE and the other one VISIBLE.  Of course this only works with a small number of backgrounds, e.g., "green" and "red" that might indicate some state.

Answer (score 1):

As of android 2.2 this method can be called, not before.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that via RemoteViews you can call just limited amount of methods. In case that it is prohibited you get message like this.

Tom

Comment: Exactly. You can only use methods that have the @RemotableViewMethod annotation

Answer (score 0):

What i find weird about this is that it works great on my nexus one ( 2.2 ), but not at all on an HTC Tattoo ( 1.6 ). I'm going to try and run some emulator tests and see if it's not just another case of HTC lazily implementing some underlying UI rendering code, which i already found with the Tattoo ( Layouts render differently than on stock Android 1.6 ).

What device were you testing this on?

Comment: Doesn't work on my 2.1 emulator. Maybe the restriction was removed in Android 2.2?? See also [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/aa000a36eadafaa5/a406589560d76784#a406589560d76784) on the android-developers group: sounds like it's a well-known limitation

Comment: Now what i do is:
views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.background, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), info.backgroundImageId) );
It's far more annoying and less efficient, but it allows me now to add downloadable themes

Answer (score 0):

The emulator will let this go through when you run a 2.2 emulator, so I guess the restriction is lifted as of 2.2.