# How to set background color for an item programmatically in listview in a widget?

Tags: android, android-widget

I have made a `Widget` following the sample code on github: [LoremWidget](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/AppWidget/LoremWidget/src/com/commonsware/android/appwidget/lorem).

I want to set different background colors for each item (not random).
I want to set the background color just below the line:

```
row.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_row_title, items[position].title)
// I want to do something similar like:
// row.findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.widget_row_root).setBackgroundColor = ...
```

The color I want to set is in the form of string like `"#e57373"`

----EDIT----

For more understanding of the problem, there is no such method for setting background color in the data provider class for a widget:

```java
public class LoremViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        // no method available for setting background color
```

Comment: That is the problem, I can't do that for a widget

Comment: row is your View. do like: row.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));

Comment: yes but that is not possible in the case of widget class, see the sample code

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453543/android-appwidget-textview-how-to-set-background-color-at-run-time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android AppWidget TextView: How to set background color at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453543/android-appwidget-textview-how-to-set-background-color-at-run-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this in the `onUpdate` method

```
remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.app_widget);

if(/*condition for changing background colour is met*/){
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_row_title, "setBackgroundColor", R.color.new_colour);
}else{
    remoteViews.setInt(R.id.widget_row_title, "setBackgroundColor", R.color.default_colour);
}
```

Comment: I think you are setting background for the whole list, I want to set it for a list item

Comment: I have written the `setInt` method in `getViewAt`, and so I don't have to care about conditions...

Answer (score 1):

Please check this updated answer:-

In the Layout that defined the main widget layout I had to add the following: android:id="@+id/LineaRLayout1"

then in in the AppWidgetProvider the onUpdate ended up looking like this, all I am really showing here is how I changed the color

just replace the id of item with your item id.

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Updating Example Widgets.");

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this
    // provider
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
        // to the button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);

        //try change color here with no luck, I tried activity_main,background, widget1

        views.setInt(R.id.LineaRLayout1, "setBackgroundColor", Color.GREEN);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pendingIntent);
        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app
        // widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```